# Color Banding Android Solution

Tags: android, eclipse, image, artifact, dithering

What is possible solution to banded images in Android Activity or in OpenGl.

Look at the answer below.

Hope it Helps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Color Banding Solved ooooooooooyyyyyyyeaaaaaaaaaa

I solved color banding in two phases

1) * when we use the BitmapFactory to decode resources it decodes the resource in RGB565 which shows color banding, instead of using ARGB_8888, so i used BitmapFactory.Options for setting the decode options to ARGB_8888

second problem was whenever i scaled the bitmap it again got banded

2) This was the tough part and took a lot of searching and finally worked
* the method Bitmap.createScaledBitmap for scaling bitmaps also reduced the images to RGB565 format after scaling i got banded images(the old method for solving this was using at least one transparent pixel in a png but no other format like jpg or bmp worked)so here i created a method CreateScaledBitmap to scale the bitmap with the original bitmaps configurations in the resulting scale bitmap(actually i copied the method from a post by logicnet.dk and translated in java)

```
    BitmapFactory.Options myOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    myOptions.inDither = true;
    myOptions.inScaled = false;
    myOptions.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888;//important
    //myOptions.inDither = false;
    myOptions.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap tempImage =  
    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),R.drawable.defaultart, myOptions);//important

    //this is important part new scale method created by someone else
    tempImage = CreateScaledBitmap(tempImage,300,300,false);

    ImageView v = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
    v.setImageBitmap(tempImage);
```

// the function

```
public static Bitmap CreateScaledBitmap(Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
{
    Matrix m = new Matrix();
    m.setScale(dstWidth  / (float)src.getWidth(), dstHeight / (float)src.getHeight());
    Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(dstWidth, dstHeight, src.getConfig());
    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(result);
    //using (var canvas = new Canvas(result))
    {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        paint.setFilterBitmap(filter);
        canvas.drawBitmap(src, m, paint);
    }
    return result;

}
```

Please correct me if i am wrong.
Also comment if it worked for you.

### I am so happy i solved it, Hope it works for you All.

For OpenGl you simply bind the bitmap created after applying upper functions