# Strange gradient in android app (background)

Tags: android, background, gradient

the background I am using for my android application looks like this:

[image: original background image]

But now when loading it into my surfaceview:

```
canvas.drawBitmap(background, 0, 0, null);
```

The result looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

Note that smooth gradient is gone!!

How should i proceed to recieve a background like the first image i uploaded?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is known as banding and is a common problem. hardware accelerated devices can handle gradients better than non accelerated devices. I suggest you do something like this:

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_accelerated="true" android:drawable="@drawable/background_grad" />
    <item android:state_accelerated="false" android:drawable="@drawable/background_no_grad" />
</selector>
```

Other suggestions such as changing the dither never worked for me. But [I'll link you to one here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452396/color-banding-android-solution).